# Python isdir returns true with string but false with variable

Tags: python

My Python script is trying to open a file of county names, read them one at a time then find a folder with the same name.  I'm using isdir to make sure the directory exists first. The print testpath statement shows me what is being tested.

When I use testpath as the argument in isdir, it returns FALSE.  When I put output of the print testpath as the isdir argument, it evaluates to TRUE.

Can anyone explain why the testpath variable returns FALSE?
Thanks

```
import sys, string, os

rootdir = 'y:/data/test'
county_list = "u:/sortedcounties.txt"

# Open county_list file and read first name.
os.path.exists(county_list)
os.path.isfile(county_list)
infile = open(county_list,'r')
line =  infile.readline()
while line:
   testpath = os.path.join(rootdir, line)
   print testpath
   if os.path.isdir(testpath):
        print 'testpath = true = ' + testpath

line = infile.readline()
```

Comment: As Jakob Bowyer points out in his answer, `infile.readline()` includes the line ending in its return value.  Change this to `infile.readline().rstrip()` and your code will work fine.  I would encourage you to skip the `os.path.isdir` test and just try to open the file and catch an IOError if it fails.  This is known in Python circles as EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission).  See http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-May/203039.html

Answer (score 4):

The way that you are reading the files is the cause of this bug. 
doing `.readline()` on a file like object returns the next line as a string WITHOUT stripping the `'\n'` value. Here is an example of this

```
from StringIO import StringIO
a = StringIO()
a.write("test\nTest")
a.seek(0)
print repr(a.readline())
```

To fix this problem you could replace your code with just iterating directly over the file itself like so

```
for line in open("filename"):
    line = line.strip()
```

Its even better to abstract this one layer further and use a context manager like so

```
with open("filename") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()
# When you leave this block then the file is flushed and closed for you in a nice clean way
```

Comment: Right diagnosis, wrong solution.  This code `for line in open("filename")` still leaves the newline intact as well.

Comment: +1 Also the context manager closes the file far more reliably (the interpreter would have to crash for it to leak the file), even with better (non-refcounting) GCs.

Comment: Thanks for those answers, they have propelled me to the next step in the program. I had tried stripping earlier but something else probably didn't work then.  I also was reading from what started as a Tab delimited file so it was full of \t's.  I don't know where else to add this but I also discovered that a blank line after my last county name would cause the testpath to be a folder short,   but it would evaluate to True because the shorter path exists. Something else to test for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change your definition of `line()` to:

```
line = infile.readline().strip()
```

The line you read will include the line's trailing newline, which is not part of the filename.

Also, keep in mind that these two lines have no effect:

```
os.path.exists(county_list)
os.path.isfile(county_list)
```

These functions return `False` if the test fails, but you do not store or test the return value. Also, opening the file will get an error if the file doesn't exist or isn't a file anyway, so this test is not strictly necessary. Finally, if you do use these tests, it is only necessary to use `isfile()` -- a file that doesn't exist is not a file, so `isfile()` catches both paths that aren't files and paths that don't exist.